# What's the difference between [Out] and out in C#?

Tags: c#, out

I've seen both when looking up P/Invoke definitions... sometimes `[Out]` is used, and sometimes `out`... I'm assuming they're the same.

Comment: `out` and `[out]` both are equivilent both tells the compiler that the object will be initialized inside the function.

Comment: Wrong answers here, look at the duplicate.

Comment: I suppose whether the answers here can be considered correct depends on how relaxed the you take the definition of "equivalent" to be.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817457/1404637) suggest to me that the differences probably shouldn't be glossed over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the equivalent to each other when used in the context of `P/Invoke` - see [OutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> You can apply the OutAttribute to value and reference types passed by reference to change In/Out behavior to Out-only behavior, which is equivalent to using the out keyword in C#.

Comment: It should be noted that they're equivalent to each other only for P/Invoke and COM interop, not in other situations as well.

Comment: @marceln I have updated for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to James answer, note that the out contextual keyword is used in two contexts:

- As a parameter modifier in parameter lists
- In generic type parameter declarations in interfaces and delegates

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx