# C# - Why do I need to initialize an [Out] parameter

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, out

I have a couple of methods imported from a native .dll, using the following syntax:

```
internal static class DllClass {
    [DllImport("Example.dll", EntryPoint = "ExampleFunction")]
    public static extern int ExampleFunction([Out] ExampleStruct param);
}
```

Now, because I specified `param` as `[Out]`, I would expect at least one of the following snippets to be valid:

```
ExampleStruct s;
DllCass.ExampleFunction(s);

ExampleStruct s;
DllCass.ExampleFunction([Out] s);

ExampleStruct s;
DllCass.ExampleFunction(out s);
```

However, none of them works. The only way I found to make it work was by initializing s.

```
ExampleStruct s = new ExampleStruct();
DllCass.ExampleFunction(s);
```

I have managed to fix that by rewriting the first snippet to the following code, but that feels kinda redundant.

```
internal static class DllClass {
    [DllImport("Example.dll", EntryPoint = "ExampleFunction")]
    public static extern int ExampleFunction([Out] out ExampleClass param);
}
```

I've read [What's the difference between [Out] and out in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16835906/1661358) and because the accepted answer states that `[Out]` and `out` are equivalent in the context, it left me wondering why it didn't work for me and if my "solution" is appropriate.

**Should I use both? Should I use only `out`? Should I use only `[Out]`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OutAttribute` determines the **runtime** behavior of the parameter, but it has no impact at **compile time**. The `out` keyword is required if you want to use compile-time semantics.

Using just the `out` keyword will change the runtime marshaling, so the `OutAttribute` is optional. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593413/1620220) for more info.

Comment: Ok, so, assuming I don't want compile-time semantics, will the code with initialization actually work? (That is, will I get a correct value in `param`?) And, suppose I do, will it work if I keep both `out` and `[Out]`?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes to both, provided the external function is written correctly to expect an `out` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing it to a value *inside* the function? That's where the requirement comes in: `out` parameters must be assigned to at least once within the function which declares the parameter.

Comment: Since this is an external dll, I doubt the compiler knows what's inside the function.

Comment: Even if I weren't, wasn't this supposed to give me an error on the function definition instead of on the call?

Comment: How does this answer the question? It seems to me that this should be posted as a comment, since it is only asking for clarification